# PHP snippet not working as I expected

Tags: php

I have this variable: `$logged_in_person_rsvp` - its value = -1

Then I run this code:

```
$yes_checked = ($logged_in_person_rsvp===1) ? "checked" : "";
$maybe_checked = ($logged_in_person_rsvp===-1) ? "checked" : "";
$no_checked = ($logged_in_person_rsvp===0) ? "checked" : "";

echo '<p>logged_in_person_rsvp: '.$maybe_checked.'</p>';
```

And I get output as nothing.  But I was expecting the output to be -1

Anyone understand why? This is weird syntax I inherited :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using two equals signs like "==" instead of 3 and see if that makes a difference. If so, your strict comparison is probably messing up your intended result.

Comment: I'm thinking the same -- in your code you may have $logged_in_person_rsvp to be a string or float (more likely) instead of expected int. Try `var_dump($logged_in_person_rsvp);` and see the output.

Answer (score 3):

you have echoed `$maybe_checked`

and `$maybe_checked` would be either "checked" or "", how would you expect it to be -1?

echoing `$logged_in_person_rsvp` should output -1

===================

Respond to your comment:

then try use operator `==` instead

`===` is strict comparison between two variables

Comment: Yes you are right.  It was my typo.  I was expecting the value to be "checked"

Answer (score 1):

Ternary operations should be enclosed in parentheses.

```
$maybe_checked = ($logged_in_person_rsvp===-1 ? "checked" : "");
```

That should do the trick.

EDIT: Also, make sure that your `$logged_in_person_rsvp` is -1 the integer, not '-1' the string. Or try using == instead of ===.

Answer (score 1):

The value of each one of these variables will be either "checked" or "", depending on the result of the operation in the brackets.

```
($logged_in_person_rsvp===-1) ? "checked" : "";
```

basically, what this does is check whether $logged_in_person_rsvp===-1 is true or false. If it is true, the variable will be assigned "checked", if it is false, the variable will be assigned "".

Answer (score 1):

The ternary syntax is often confusing for newcomers. This is an alternative way using an array-map to express your code:

```
$checked = array(FALSE => "", TRUE => "checked");

$yes_checked =   $checked[($logged_in_person_rsvp===1)];
$maybe_checked = $checked[($logged_in_person_rsvp===-1)];
$no_checked =    $checked[($logged_in_person_rsvp===0)];

echo '<p>logged_in_person_rsvp: '.$maybe_checked.'</p>';
```

The `===` is just a strict version of the normal equal `==` operator.

Comment: Just tried to do what you did there, but it didn't output "checked" - any idea why not?

Comment: You can try to use the less strict comparison `==` operator. If you say the variable `$logged_in_person_rsvp` contains a `-1` beforehand, then that `-1` could be a string instead of an integer. In hindsight the `===` type-equality operator might be totally unneeded here.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `var_dump($logged_in_person_rsvp);` (or inspecting the value in xdebug, or firephp, or your choice of debugger) to determine what type `$logged_in_person_rsvp` is?

Using the snippet you provided, if I set:

```
$logged_in_person_rsvp = -1;
```

everything works fine, and I get `<p>logged_in_person_rsvp: checked</p>` but if I set:

```
$logged_in_person_rsvp = "-1";
```

then I get `<p>logged_in_person_rsvp: </p>`

As it has been pointed out by others, `==` will try to cast the two sides of the comparison to the same type, but `===` will check type as well and fail if one is a string and one is an int/float.